# What is the $x$-intercept of this straight line equation?

Tags: graphing-functions

$y=-2x+1$

I found the $x$-intercept by setting $y= 0$ so here goes:

$$0=-2x+1\implies -1=-2x\implies x=\frac{1}{2}$$

The sketch I saw of this graph though ,has a different $x$-intercept.

How could I work this out properly ?

Comment: Your calculation above is correct. The sketch must either be incorrect or you looked at the $x$-intercept wrong. The $x$-intercept is indeed $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Is it possible for you to show us that sketch?

Comment: Sorry I'm not very good with computers.

Comment: Just copy y=−2x+1 and paste it on *the* Google :-)

Comment: What is the $x$-intercept you found from your sketch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've found the correct $x$-intercept, $(\frac{1}{2},0)$. Perhaps you've made a typo in your graphing, or the axes could be scaled in a strange way that make it look wrong. Here is the graph of the line from WolframAlpha, with the x-intercept pointed out:

[image: y=-2x+1]